# CollabNet SVN Edge and VisualSVN on the same server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, collabnet, subversion-edge

I currently have CollabNet SVN ("SubversionEdge") installed on a shared server. I would like to install VisualSVN on the same server (for comparison purposes, as we are considering migrating). What sort of conflicts might I encounter or what problems can I anticipate? These will both be relatively low-volume installations.

(I'm asking because I recall our previous admin had all sorts of headaches installing SVN and JIRA (both with AD/LDAP) on the same server; port conflicts and such as I recall).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install VisualSVN Server on another HTTP(S) port than Subversion Edge. It will work without conflicts. (Make sure that the port is available and not blocked, though).

Active Directory integration works out-of-the-box in VisualSVN Server and does not require you to setup LDAP settings manually. No conflicts are expected here.